# Create a computed DataTime Column by combining Date and Time Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a computed datetime column by combining date and time column but i get an error.

this what i have tried:

```
CAST(Date as DATETIME) + CAST(Time as DATETIME)
```

**Error:**

*error while validating the formula for the DateTimeConso column*

[image]

Any idea what's going wrong with cast or way of creating computed column ?

Comment: Be wary of this formula, though. While using `CAST` and "adding" `DATETIME` instances certainly looks convenient, the results are dependent on language settings when using strings and can even end up as nonsensical if you don't take care that dates always have no time. Consider more stable approaches like `DATETIMEFROMPARTS`/`DATEPART` and `CONVERT` with an explicit style (depending on your input types). Also, consider the `DATETIME2` type for both better precision and actual control over how much precision you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graphical UI is flaky at best. `ALTER` the table "properly" using SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD NewColumn AS CAST([Date] as DATETIME) + CAST([Time] as DATETIME);
```

Note that if the column `[Time]` has a precision of more than 1/100 of a second, accuracy will be lost with this method.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it using select query

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), Date , 112) 
      + ' ' + CONVERT(CHAR(8), Time , 108))
      FROM table_name;
```